# Keeping prestige up as Castille

Tags: europa-universalis-3

I've been attempting to claim heir to the throne of Aragon, which means I have to keep my prestige higher than theirs as I understand it. However, while I try as I may, somehow my prestige sometimes  tanks. Is this due to loans? Stability? What are some strategies to make sure I get that throne?

Comment: Does it drop suddenly or is it constantly decreasing? If it's constantly decreasing, you can hover over the prestige icon to find out why (it's generally from uncontested core provinces).

Comment: It generally just drops suddenly, though.

Answer (score 2):

Claiming the throne costs prestige, as does refusing to honor a call to arms. The best strategy to get the throne is to simply hire a strong (4+ star) advisor who will raise prestige/keep it high, and concentrate on keeping only one throne at a time.